# how to replace a variable X with a data at index 0 of an array which has value 'X'

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, promise

```
    this.work[0].minValue = await this.getData().then(
      value => value[0].set.min.X
    )
    this.work[1].minValue = await this.getData().then(
      value => value[0].set.min.Y
    )
    this.work[2].minValue = await this.getData().then(
      value => value[0].set.min.Z
    )
    this.work[3].minValue = await this.getData().then(
      value => value[0].set.min.A
    )
    this.work[4].minValue = await this.getData().then(
      value => value[0].set.min.B
    )
    this.work[5].minValue = await this.getData().then(
      value => value[0].set.min.C
    )
```

I am trying to write this 6 lines of code inside a loop, which i am not able to do it. Could someone help me out.

```
var arr = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C']
    var i = 0
    var that = this
    this.work.forEach(item => {
      item.minValue = that.getData().then(value => value[0].set.min.that.arr[i])
      i++
    })
```

i know this is wrong with ***min.that.arr[i]***.Please dont say its reason why it not working, Please help me out with the solution.

Comment: value[0].set.min[that.arr[i]]

Comment: The code seems to be in a class and if I understand correctly your `this`, `getData` doesn't depend on each `work` item, and should be called only once, outside of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***value[0].set.min[arr[i]]***

what ashkan suggested fixed my issue.

Comment: If so, Ashkan's comment should be an answer, and this answer should be a comment. I still think you call `getData` too many times uselessly. Some problems need a bit more reflexion than applying the first working suggestion, and careless coders can put themselves in bad situations when it starts to bug..

Answer (score 1):

The action should be in the `then`:

```
var arr = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C']
var i = 0
var that = this
this.work.forEach(item => {
  that.getData().then(value => item.minValue = value[0].set.min.that.arr[i++])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you only need one call to `getData` outside of the loop, no need to do it at each loop turn.
Also, you don't need `i` as a var, as it can be provided as an argument in the `forEach` callback function:

```
var arr = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C']
var that = this
await that.getData().then(
    value => {
        that.work.forEach((item, i) => {
            item.minValue = value[0].set.min[arr[i]]
        })
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because the `then` is asynchronous. At the point the callback is made `i` will have the maximum value for all callbacks (meaning `5` in the provided example).

Instead use the index provided by the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop (second argument provided to the callback function).

```
const arr = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C'];

this.work.forEach((item, index) => {
  const chr = arr[index];
  this.getData().then(value => {
    item.minValue = value[0].set.min[chr];
  });
});

// or using an async arrow function
this.work.forEach(async (item, index) => {
  const chr = arr[index];
  const value = await this.getData();
  item.minValue = value[0].set.min[chr];
});
```

Note that it's probably not a good idea to make the same asynchronous call each iteration and you most likely want to move the data request before the loop. I'll assume the wrapping function is already using the `async` keyword, since you also use `await this.getData()` in your example.

```
const arr = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C'];
const value = await this.getData();

this.work.forEach((item, index) => {
  const chr = arr[index];
  item.minValue = value[0].set.min[chr];
});
```

You can find more about your `i` issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).